# Simple quiz won't wait for an answer

Tags: java, if-statement

I have been trying to make a simple quiz as part of an online exercise, I have 2 questions with an if statement that should only accept 1 of 3 possible outcomes, the correct answer, the wrong answer or an incorrect selection.

My problem is, when the user makes and incorrect selection eg A B or C and the user presses Q the program skips to the next question without waiting for either a correct or incorrect answer. To my knowledge the if statement should not allow the program to flow unless the conditions are met, yet still an incorrect selection moves to the next question regardless.

Please be brutal in your responses, I have a feeling the methods I have learned are more than a little out of date.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class quiz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a;
        String b;
        String c;
        String name;
        int score = 0;

        System.out.println("Welcome to your new quiz !");
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome " + name + " let's start the quiz !");
        System.out.println("What is Ireland's capitol city?");
        System.out.println("Is it\n\t\tA)Dublin\n\t\tB)Galway\n\t\tC)Cork\n");
        System.out.println("Please select A B or C");
        System.out.println("Your current score is " + score);
        String q;
        q = scan.nextLine();

        if (q.toLowerCase().equals("a")) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            score = score + 1;
            System.out.println("Your new score is " + score);
        } else if (q.toLowerCase().equals("b")) {
            System.out.println("Sorry that was incorrect!");
        } else if (q.toLowerCase().equals("c")) {
            System.out.println("Sorry that was incorrect!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You pressed " + q + " Please choose A B or C");
        }

        System.out.println("Second Question !!");
        System.out.println("What was the currency unit for Ireland before the Euro was introduced?");
        System.out.println("Is it\n\t\tA)Pound\n\t\tB)Dollar\n\t\tC)Punt\n");
        System.out.println("Please select A B or C");
        System.out.println("Your current score is " + score);
        String w;
        w = scan.nextLine();

        if (w.toLowerCase().equals("c")) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            score = score + 1;
            System.out.println("Your new score is " + score);
        } else if (w.toLowerCase().equals("b")) {
            System.out.println("Sorry that was incorrect!");
        } else if (w.toLowerCase().equals("a")) {
            System.out.println("Sorry that was incorrect!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You pressed " + w + " Please choose A B or C");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know now that condition 3, incorrect selection, has been met and the program advances. I would like to know how to force it to wait for condition 1 or 2 please.

Comment: I suggest you look at `Do While` loops to achieve this.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in my comment, a loop would be needed here with a boolean flag.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Placing your `While` condition at the bottom of the `Do` loop will insure that the code within the loop is run at least once.
If you place the condition at the top like this:

```
while (guessed){
    // your code goes here
}
```

then if the condition is already met, the code block wont be executed.

```
System.out.println("Second Question !!");
        System.out.println("What was the currency unit for Ireland before the Euro was introduced?");
        System.out.println("Is it\n\t\tA)Pound\n\t\tB)Dollar\n\t\tC)Punt\n");
        System.out.println("Please select A B or C");
        System.out.println("Your current score is " + score);
        String w;
        boolean guessed = false;
        do{
            w = scan.nextLine();
            if (w.toLowerCase().equals("c")) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                score = score + 1;
                System.out.println("Your new score is " + score);
                guessed = true;
            } else if (w.toLowerCase().equals("b")) {
                System.out.println("Sorry that was incorrect!");
                guessed = true;
            } else if (w.toLowerCase().equals("a")) {
                System.out.println("Sorry that was incorrect!");
                guessed = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You pressed " + w + " Please choose A B or C");
            }
        }while (!guessed);
```

Comment: That is a great answer Vahx, thanks a lot. I hope the haze of confusion eventually fades away and I can begin to become good at this stuff. Thanks for taking time to help a newbie.

Comment: Just a note - you'll need to put `w = scan.nextLine()` inside the do block to prevent an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a loop in your program, so that it will continually ask for the answer until a valid response is entered. A while loop could achieve this, as follows:

Define a boolean (true/false) variable, that you will use to track whether a valid response has been made:

```
boolean validResponse = false;
```

And then use this in a while loop, to repeatedly ask the question if necessary:

```
while (!validResponse) {
    q = scan.nextLine();
    if (q.toLowerCase().equals("a")) {
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        score++;
        System.out.println("Your new score is " + score);
        validResponse = true;
    }
    // else if 'b', if 'c', etc.
    if (!validResponse) {
        System.out.println("You pressed " +q+" Please choose A B or C");
    }
}
```

The code inside your while loop will be run repeatedly, until the test fails - in this case, when `validResponse` is set to true. At this point, the program will continue with whatever follows the loop.

There are better ways to implement this program, but I tried to change as little of your code as possible. For example, you would want to store the questions and answers in a data structure, and iterate through this, rather than repeating almost identical blocks of code for every question.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I'm sure this only gets easier... right? :)

Comment: Hehe, sort of... the more you learn, the more complicated the problems you want to solve become, but it's all good fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code will look something like this:

```
    boolean correctAnswer = false;
    do {
        w = scan.nextLine();
        if (w.toLowerCase().equals("c")){
            score++; //same as score = score + 1;
            correctAnswer = true;
            System.out.println("Correct! Your new score is " +score);
        }else if (w.toLowerCase().equals("b")){
            System.out.println("Sorry that was incorrect!");
        }else if (w.toLowerCase().equals("a")){
            System.out.println("Sorry that was incorrect!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("You pressed " +w+" Please choose A B or C"); 
        }
    } while (!correctAnswer);
```

Comment: Thanks Micheal, not everyday I get this much support, thanks for helping the new guy :)